# How to get value by reference from WIN32OLE::ARGV?

Tags: ruby, com, win32ole

Below code returns 0

```
v = 0
obj.foo('',0)
printf("v : %d \n",  WIN32OLE::ARGV[1])
```

when really it must return another value by reference.

For example in python it works like here:

```
v = obj.foo('')
print('v : %d' % v)
```

I don't get yet how to make same on Ruby.

Comment: Can you show what your code should return,and what you are getting currently? And what is `foo`.. Give us the exact scenarios if possible..

Comment: `[id(DISPID_FOO)] HRESULT foo([in] BSTR a, [in, out] DWORD *b);`

Comment: what is this? still did not get you..

Comment: it's foo definition in idl. should be enough information to get `b` value.